# Aurelia bind to inline object

Tags: aurelia

I am developing an app in aurelia and I have a straight question. These bindings are working fine:

```
<input some-custom-attribute="name.bind: myName;"/>
```

and this too:

```
<input some-custom-attribute="name: 'some name';"/>
```

but about objects. This does work:

```
<input some-custom-attribute="options.bind: someObject;"/>
```

but this doesn't:

```
<input some-custom-attribute="options.bind: {inlineObject: 12};"/>
```

and also this (does not):

```
<input some-custom-attribute="options: {inlineObject: 12};"/>
```

So how can I pass an inline object in options binding in Aurelia?

Comment: what is actually happening? do you have an error in the console? the objects remains `undefine`?

Comment: I receive a string instead of object. in the `propertyChanged` method, I expect to receive `newValue = {'someproperty': somevalue};` but instead I get `newValue = "{'someproperty': somevalue}";`.

Comment: This is a bug in Aurelia, I think you will have to work around this atm.

Comment: Maybe do something like `JSON.parse(newValue)` in your `some-custom-attribute` logic

Comment: @classicalConditioning of course by now I am doing it this way. But I expect a better solution from aurelia. As my custom attribute has dynamic properties, then I should recognize which properties to parse (that are object) and which to not (string, number , etc.). So although by now I am using parsing way (for retrieved strings starting with '{') but I think this is not a good way.